# Not able to scrape entire table using pd.read_html

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, pandas

I tried using pd.read_html to scrape a table, but the last 3 columns are returning "nan".  Here is the code I used:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.actionnetwork.com/mlb/public-betting'

todays_games = pd.read_html(url)[0]
```

There are 7 columns in total, and it grabs all of the headers, but not the data in the last 3 columns.  I also tried parsing this using BeautifulSoup, but got the same result.

```
print(todays_games)

                                                Scheduled      Open  ... Diff Bets
    0                5:05 PM 951MarlinsMIA952NationalsWSH  -118+100  ...  NaN  NaN
    1                   5:10 PM 979BrewersMIL980TigersDET  -227+188  ...  NaN  NaN
    2                    7:07 PM 965RaysTB966Blue JaysTOR  +150-175  ...  NaN  NaN
    3                 8:10 PM 967Red SoxBOS968MarinersSEA  -125+105  ...  NaN  NaN
    4                    10:35 PM 953RedsCIN954PiratesPIT  -154+135  ...  NaN  NaN
    5                   11:05 PM 955CubsCHC956PhilliesPHI  +170-200  ...  NaN  NaN
    6                 11:05 PM 969YankeesNYY970OriolesBAL  -227+188  ...  NaN  NaN
    7                  11:10 PM 957CardinalsSTL958MetsNYM  +135-154  ...  NaN  NaN
    8                  11:20 PM 959RockiesCOL960BravesATL  +170-200  ...  NaN  NaN
    9                   11:40 PM 971IndiansCLE972TwinsMIN  +100-118  ...  NaN  NaN
    10       Thu 9/16, 12:05 AM 973AstrosHOU974RangersTEX  -213+175  ...  NaN  NaN
    11     Thu 9/16, 12:10 AM 975AngelsLAA976White SoxCWS  +160-189  ...  NaN  NaN
    12      Thu 9/16, 12:10 AM 977AthleticsOAK978RoyalsKC  -149+125  ...  NaN  NaN
    13           Thu 9/16, 1:45 AM 961PadresSD962GiantsSF  +103-120  ...  NaN  NaN
    14  Thu 9/16, 2:10 AM 963DiamondbacksARI964DodgersLAD  -185+155  ...  NaN  NaN
```

I'm assuming the problem has something to do with the HTML code.  Can anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send HTTP GET to https://api.actionnetwork.com/web/v1/scoreboard/mlb?bookIds=15,30,68,75,69,76,71,79,247,123,263&date=20210915

and get the data you are looking for.

```
import requests

r = requests.get(
    'https://api.actionnetwork.com/web/v1/scoreboard/mlb?bookIds=15,30,68,75,69,76,71,79,247,123,263&date=20210915')
print(r.json())
```

Comment: where did you find that api endpoint? I'm trying to access some other data from actionnetwork.com but can't find api documentation anywhere.  I'm specifically looking for team ATS data and some previous schedule data.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!